# laravel share variable across all methods in a controller

Tags: php, variables, layout, controller, laravel

i am making a simple website in PHP laravel framework where the top navigation links are being generated dynamically from the database. I am generating the $pages variable in the home controller action and passing to layout file. My code is as below:

```
 public function home()
{
    $pages = Page::all();
    return View::make('home')->with('pages', $pages);
}

public function login()
{
    return View::make('login');
}
```

But when i try to access the login action, i get the error variable $pages not found since the $pages variable is being accessed in layout file. How  can i share the same variable across all the actions in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Laravel's view composer. I made a header.blade.php and passed the $pages variable to it and added following code to my routes.php file.

```
View::composer('header', function($view){
   $pages = Page::all();
   $view->with('pages', $pages);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I think a fairly straightforward way to do this is by using the controller's constructor. It's sometimes helpful to be able to see the vars available to all methods in a controller from within that controller, instead of hidden away in a service provider somewhere.

```
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('sharedVar', 'some value');
    }

    public function myTestAction()
    {
        view('view.name.here');
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<p>{{ $sharedVar }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use singleton like the following

```
App::singleton('data', function() { return array('abc' => 1); });
```

This way, you can call it anywhere in your controller or template like

```
$data = App::make('data');
```

Following this, you could try using a bundle developed by Phil here, https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting. Once installed, then you can just refer it in controller or template by

```
Setting::get('title')
```

Of course, you can set it anywhere by using

```
Setting::set('title', 'Portfolio');
```

Setting allows you store them both in cache and json file which might be another way to get the value back.

Answer (score 1):

### Share Variables

*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider*:

```
# app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php


public function boot()
{
   // add this
    view()->share('someKey', 'This is shared data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add as a parameter inside your login action.

```
public function login()
{
    $pages = Page::all();
    return View::make('login')->with('pages',$pages);
}
```

---

### My older reply:

To  share the same variable across all the actions in a controller, raw PHP should help you out:

```
<?php

Class MyController Extends BaseController {
    var $pages = Page::all();

     public function home()
    {
        return View::make('home')->with('pages', $this->pages);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $pages = $this->pages;
        return View::make('login');
    }
}
```

But personally, I would prefer making a variable in model, something like:

```
<?php

Class Page extends Eloquent {

    public static $all_ages = Page::all();
}
```

And access it like:

```
Page::$all_pages;
```

Comment: you are mixing JavaScript and PHP