# Laravel private variable shared between two methods in Controller

Tags: php, methods, laravel, laravel-4, share

How to use private variable in Laravel Controller, and share that variable value between two methods. (Set it in one use it in another).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're talking about one single controller, right? So I'll assume that this what you mean:

```
class ControllerController extends Controller {

    private $variable;

    public function __construct($whatever)
    {
        $this->variable = $whatever;
    }

    public function method1($newValue)
    {
        $this->variable = $newValue;
    }

    public function method2()
    {
        return $this->variable;
    }

}
```

If you are doing thing in the same request, you can

```
$this->method1('newvalue');

echo $this->method2();
```

And it will print `newvalue`.

If you are doing it between requests, you need to remember that your application ends after a request a restart in a new one, so you'll need to store it somewhere, like in a Session variable:

```
Session::put('variable', $newvalue);
```

and then

```
Session::get('variable');
```

Or you can redirect with the value you need to get back in your method:

```
Redirect::to('posts')->with('variable','this is a new value');
```

And in the second

```
Session::get('variable');
```

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that in method2 it prints NULL and I am using argument of method1 to set private variable value.

Comment: Is this happening between requests or in the same request?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Setting approach outlined here

[laravel share variable across all methods in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722033/laravel-share-variable-across-all-methods-in-a-controller/24120525#24120525)

and

[Laravel: Passing default variables to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645087/laravel-passing-default-variables-to-view/24247409#24247409)

and you can download Setting here, https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting