# How to pass parameters between controller methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am having problems getting the value of custom create method. What I want is to get the variable $student_id and place it on my findOrFail() in the index method as shown below:

ReservationController.php

```
public function index()
{

    $student = Student::with(['sectionSubjects','sectionSubjects.section', 
                'sectionSubjects.subject'])->findOrFail(1); //$student_id

    return $student->sectionSubjects;    

}

public function create($id)
{
    $student_id = $id;

    $subjects = Subject::with('sections')->get();

    return view('reservation.form',compact('subjects','student_id'));
}
```

Here's my route:

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::resource('reservation', 'ReservationController', ['except' => ['create','show'] ]);

Route::get('reservation/{id}/create', 
    ['as' => 'reservation.create', 'uses' => 'ReservationController@create'
]);
```

I have this form.blade.php that when a user click on a student it will be redirected to the custom create method in the ReservationController as seen below:

```
<div class="list-group ">
@inject('student', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentController')
    @foreach($student->index() as $s)
        <div class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                {{ $s->first_name }} {{ $s->middle_name }} {{ $s->last_name }}</i>
            </h4>
            <h5>
               ID No.: {{ $s->id_no }}</i>
            </h5>

           <a href="{{ route('student.edit', $s->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit Info</a>

           <a href="{{ route('reservation.create', $s->id ) }}" 
              class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
              Enroll
            </a> 

        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
```

Now in the index method in the ReservationController, I want to fetch only values that are related to that $student_id. However, I cannot figure out to achieve this. Can anyone suggest ways to solve this?

Comment: I really don't understand. Can you simplify your question ?

Comment: @xdevnull What I want is to get the id parameter of this route Route::get('reservation/{id}/create' and be accessible in my index method in the reservationcontroller

Comment: index should be access from somewhere else, You need to call index manually or put some private members. However this would work for ```single request``` for more than one request you may store it in session or somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel private variable shared between two methods in Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692109/laravel-private-variable-shared-between-two-methods-in-controller)

Comment: @xdevnull Okay so in my index method in the reservationcontroller I am fetching the student. The problem there is that it is hard coded. What I want is that $id value be the value of the id in the Route::get('reservation/{id}/create . The problem is, the id is only accessible for the create method. What I want is to get the id (in that case $student_id). That is what I want to achieve.

Comment: It wont be possible only using ```Session``` but i wouldn't recommend. Re-arrange your routes is better thing. Keep in mind. Viewing a singular 'Model' requires a parameter to be passed somehow. Or u call ```index()``` from ```create()``` method but probably this will break somestuff.

Comment: @xdevnull I see. It seems that my option to call the index(). But how can I call the index()?

Comment: @xdevnull Can you please remove the possible duplicate

Comment: @xdevnull oh sorry I dont have enough reputation for the live chat

Comment: @xdevnull why I cannot type on the chat it says needs reputation

Comment: @xdevnull create new chat room thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113093/discussion-between-jearson-and-xdevnull).

Comment: @xdevnull any temporary solutions?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, You need to define custom route for adding student. (For add button), which will be something like ```reservations/{subject_id}/enroll/{student_id}```

Comment: @xdevnull Yeah I already solved it yesterday hehe. Yeah I used nested resource.

Comment: @xdevnull However I included a hidden field in my form.blade.php and combine jquery. var student_id = $("#student_id").val();  var id = this.id; url:  'http://localhost:8000/reservation/' + id + '/student',

Comment: Have you looked at security side? Have you added enough validations?

Comment: Can you contact me now in IRC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have any problem expect `Logic` problem.

Your `Controller` not designed in the correct way.

You need to have something like this

```
//List all subjects
public function index() {
    return view('reservation.form')->with('subjects', Subject::with('sections')->get());
}

//List a single subject
//If i didn't misunderstood you, you can remove this one according to the source code you're using.
public function show($id) {
    return view('reservation.oneSubject')->with('subject', Subject::find($id));
}

//Enroll a student to subject
public function enroll($id, $student_id) {
    //Find the section for $id
    //Add student_id to that section
}
```

And you need to define one extra route could be `GET` or `POST` in this example i'm using `GET`

```
Route::get('/reservation/{id}/enroll/{student_id}', 'ReservationsController@enroll');
```

**What logic should i follow?**

1. List all subjects (will call `index()`)
2. Select one subject (will call `show($id)`)
3. Show students.
4. Click add button (will call `enroll($id, $student_id)`

**How do i pass $id, $student_id to enroll?**

Your reservations resource will have these routes.

```
/reservations
/reservations/{id}/store
etc..
```

`id` parameter in your example, Pointing to `Subject` not Student.

Let's say you've a `show($id)` function which will show single subject and list of students,

```
return view(...)->with('subject', Subject::find($id)->with('students', YOUR_STUDENTS);
```

In the view, iterate through students, assuming you've `$students`

```
@foreach($students as $student)
<a href="{{ action('ReservationController@enroll', [$subject->id, $student->id']) }}">Enroll student</a>
@endforeach
```

**I don't have show() function!**

Since you don't have a show function that will display single `subject`, Same logic will apply here,

1. Iterate through subjects
2. Display subject
3. Iterate throught students
4. Generate `anchor tags` as the example above

So you'll have something like this,

```
@foreach($subjects as $subject)
<h1>{{ $subject->title }}</h1>
    @foreach($students as $student)
     <div class="students">
        <h2> {{ $student->name }}</h2>
        <a href="{{ action('ReservationController@enroll', [$subject->id, $student->id]) }}">Enroll</a>
     </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay Im online at irc