# share variables between methods laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, methods, share

i need help, to understand , how i can share variables between methods in the same controller?
In this case,i have the method imprimirFecha() and  i need get values of the variable 'servicio' that  i use in the method mostrandoFecha()

```
 class ControllerReport extends Controller
    {
    public  $desde ;
    public $hasta;
    public $servicio;


        public function mostrandoFecha(Request  $request){
      global $servicio;
           try{

             $desde=($request->input('desde'));
             $hasta=($request->input('hasta'));
             $servicio = DB::table('mivista')
                        ->whereBetween('fechap',array($desde, $hasta))->get();
        $this->servicio=$servicio;


               return view ('report.buscar_pagosFecha',compact('servicio')); 

        } catch (Exception $e){
             return ('Error - ' . $e);
        }

        }

       public function imprimirFecha(){

         $servicio=$this->servicio;
               $pdf = \PDF::loadView('report.buscar_pagosFechaPrint',$servicio); 

              return $pdf->stream('buscar_pagosFechaPrint.pdf');

        } 

        }
```

Comment: Consider that your controller is just a class; it can have private member data that you can read/write from/to.

Comment: yes, the variables was declared as public it the class

Comment: Then store it in your mostrandoFecha function with $this->servicio  = $servicio and in your imprimirFecha function you can refer to it with $this->servicio. Also it would help if you include the entire class.

Comment: @ChrisCousins already edit the code... and i use $this->servicio in the second method.. but it gives me an errror

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Whay are you using global $servicio?

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array     and yes, i declared global in the first method  as you can see in the code

Comment: What is the line number for the array_merge? Also I was asking why you added global $servicio? That is not necessary.

Comment: yes, the global i used because i think maybe was a solution... and i can see the problem is that i can't use the same data(servicio) use in the first method

Comment: You can share that data as you are doing; please remove the global statement and try again.

Comment: ok , at the beginning of the second method i print the value of servicio. and shows me: 'null'

Comment: Since its hard to know when your methods are being called; it may be best for you to return servicio to the view in mostrandoFecha and then when you call your imprimirFecha route, supply it the value given to the view. Also, I must ask, why are you wishing to store the value?

Comment: i am reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692109/laravel-private-variable-shared-between-two-methods-in-controller#