# Pass variable to function

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I want to pass a variable from a function passes to function message. I create $groupname in the else sector and try to use it in the message function query. What is in my case the best way to do this?

```
class ExistingGroupMembers implements Rule
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $existingMembers = Member::where([['idgroup', $value],['member', '<>', Auth::id()]])->select('id')->first('id');
        if(!empty($existingMembers)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $groupname = Group::where('id', $value)->select('name')->first();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'In der Gruppe ' .$groupname. ' existieren keine User!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel private variable shared between two methods in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692109/laravel-private-variable-shared-between-two-methods-in-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your variables to `$this` scope. then you can access it.

example code

```
public function passes()
{
    $this->group_name = Group::where('id', $value)->select('name')->first();
}

public function message()
{
    return 'In der Gruppe ' . $this->group_name . ' existieren keine User!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a private property of class then then set value in `passes` function then you can access that property in `message` function

```
class ExistingGroupMembers implements Rule
{

    private $groupname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $existingMembers = Member::where([['idgroup', $value],['member', '<>', Auth::id()]])->select('id')->first('id');
        if(!empty($existingMembers)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->groupname = Group::where('id', $value)->select('name')->first();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'In der Gruppe ' .$this->groupname. ' existieren keine User!';
    }
}
```